# How to build the Thrift lib (c++) for WinCE?

Tags: windows-ce, thrift

I made some attempts, it seems that MISSING the c++11 related libraries, such as can not find , etc.
HELP

Comment: add some detail to get some help. Are you trying to build the thrift compiler for WinCE or are you using some thrift compiled file to be used in your c++ wince application? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks,but Thrift lib is NOT support fo WINCE. 
"Windows version compatibility¶
The Thrift library targets Windows XP for broadest compatbility. A notable difference is in the Windows-specific implementation of the socket poll function. To target Vista, Win7 or other versions, comment out the line

#define TARGET_WIN_XP.